# What would it serve a religion to have two opposing deities with overlapping portfolios?

Tags: religion, gods

The trilogy of Enoch is a set of books within the bible that portrays the divine politics that set the foundation for the canon of its religion. While books 1 and 2 talk of the fall of the watchers and the flood which wiped out the nephilim, book three gives a vivid account of the war in heaven, when lucifer and his allies rebelled against his father. After Dea, creator of the universe, formed the earth, he placed a significant amount of power into his angels, that they may be his loyal servants. mankind was a future investment, as Dea gains compound interest from all the souls that come back to him after death. After lucifer was cast out into hell, he set about corrupting mankind by encouraging them towards sin and evil, condemning their souls to his realm for eternity and increasing his power.

However, the book also speaks of an angel named Belail that had originally been created for those purpose. Belail was ordained as the angel of darkness, meant to tempt man into wickedness and disobedience of God's will. He and his host were to whisper into man's ear and push them into sin in order to risk their eternal soul. This was in order to test man's faith, fulfilling the purpose of free will. Man can choose to disobey God and submit to his baser instincts, or rise above his desires and remain steadfast.

Since Lucifer took the stage as the ultimate evil meant to corrupt humanity, it makes Belail's role somewhat redundant. You essentially have two angels going around and doing the same thing for the same reasons, except one still works for heaven and one works for his own interests. This makes Dea look incompetent, as not only is he a bad divider of his resources, but has stacked the deck against his creation, humanity, increasing their likely fall into sin and damnation.

How can I justify keeping Beliail around when he appears to be a self inflicting wound?

Comment: Why do you _need_ to justify the character's existence? Just bin them, or claim it was the same character wearing a false nose and beard to confuse people.

Comment: (1) Even as described, the two angels do not do the same thing, not even remotely. It is like saying that an FBI agent working undercover to reveal a drug importing ring does the same thing as the actual drug importers. (2) A religion and the mythology of that religion are very different things. For example, Islam, Christianity and Judaism share very large of their mythology: and yet they are strikingly different religions. (3) Discerning the why the book says what it says is a very complicated task, one which should not be attempted by untrained laypersons. Go read a good book of exegesis.

Comment: You mean doppelgänger, they are somewhat twin but one of them has a bad luck ;D

Comment: What's the use of being an evil overlord without henchmen?

Comment: Have you looked at the roman gods many things like war, or the underworld for instance had more than one god.

Answer (score 5):

## A Problematic Assumption

There is a BIG assumption here- that a divine being needs to be the perfect example or aspect of some attribute of life, society, or natural phenomenon and other beings must either be aligned with them or are excluded from that example/aspect. Broadly speaking, this is very rarely the case!

I am going to just choose war in this example, since that is fairly common in pantheons.  [Athena/Minerva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athena) and [Aries/Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ares) are both war deities. *All* Norse gods are gods of battle/war. Aztec famously have a lot of warrior/warrioress dieties. The list can go on- real-life deities share portfolios while being of equal magnitude/importance.

In terms of worship, this can be as simple as who you like better or what sub-aspects of a particular thing you want. This can also bring out the idea (in the case of negative divine figures) that there isn't just one "evil", but many evil things out there.

As far as mythologies go, you don't need an ultimate good / ultimate evil, nor do some class of beings need to be aligned to one of them in a hierarchy. This presents things like [Blue-and-Orange Morality](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlueAndOrangeMorality), where choices (and deities!) are just different, not inherently good or bad.

## Just Doing His Job (And You Should, Too)

This is a simple moral to be gained from this. Individuals should complete their purpose. This other tempter is just doing his job, like he's supposed to, and that's ok.

## To Grade Evil

Finally, maybe his temptations have different consequences: perhaps they are not being purely destructive or malignant. Alternatively, maybe his temptations are considered "lesser" and are more easily forgiven, letting a religion distinguish between little and severe evils. After all, saying you took out the trash and didn't vs saying you didn't kill a person but did have *very* different consequences! Likewise, lying and murder have different consequences and different degrees to which they can be rectified. Having two sources for the temptations here can make sense.

Answer (score 4):

**White hat, Black hat**.  It sounds like your Dea knew Lucifer (the black hat hacker, the actual threat) was going to try to tempt people, and did some internal security testing first.  So your Bilial is a White Hat hacker, catching the lusers slipping and presumably setting them up for a sternly worded warning from the IT Department.

Comment: Pretty much the answer I would have developed, but in the language of the question, not of digital hat-colours. BTW, wouldn't that make Bilial a grey-hat?

Comment: The way I interpreted the question, he's explicitly working for the company.by permission.

Comment: Well, yes. But delving into the depths of depravity.. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

#### One's a gateway drug to the other

The devil is pretty hardcore. There's a lot of power there, and the deals humanity make with the devil are not made under any false pretenses. Eg "I give you my soul in hell for eternity after my death in return for you halting aging and giving me magic super powers on earth". Human thinks he'll rule for eternity as a god and has tricked the devil, Lucifer knows he'll get stabbed by an underling eventually and always wins in the end.

Bilial? Well he's just Bilial, he's just a bit of fun. The deals humanity makes with Bilial are low key; "I get a promotion at work and a payrise in return for never attending church again". The deals are attractive to new humans. After they've hit these low key deals a few times and are looking for something a bit more powerful, Bilial introduces them to his "friend" who can help them out.

Dea only sees good returns on souls over a certain purity level, if an impure soul enters heaven it's influence will start to spread, (and then they'll be in lockdown and social distancing - urgh), so it's in Dea's best interest to have lucifer removing the bottom level souls. But humanity is smart, and some people avoid lucifer only because of his reputation, **not because of his offer of power**. Bilial is there to temp those who are still corruptible but refuse the obvertness of the devil.

Answer (score 0):

**Their functions overlap, but not the consequences of their actions**

Belial is a temptator, but a bad one. He literally tries to persuade people to do bad actions that will soon backfire. Like telling a little boy to steal the marmelade (in a mement when his mother can see him) or a high-school student to mock the bad grades of the football team quarterback...
Of course Belial works for the greater good, and his real purpose is to show by example how "crime does not pay", both to the tempted one and the "audience". And anyway, his temptations rely on "occasional" (and somehow forgivable) bad deeds, rather than on life changing actions, so that the soul is never really lost to the cause.

Lucifer's motto, instead, is "crime does not pay, it's on me!": his temptations are smarter and rarely backfire (in the short term), so that people who are tempted by him really fall into the rabbit hole of evil and are definitively lost.

The temptations of Lucifer and Belial also work as an example to other people: somebody could see a bad action rewarded with wealth and success and act accordingly (badly). Somebody else could see a bad action receive a harsh punishment and act accordingly (as a good person).